# Cannot mount LVM2 partitions

Tags: mount, lvm, elementary-os

I have a 160GB hard drive here with an LVM2 partition that contains two EXT3 partitions that I'm trying to mount.

However, when I try to mount either of those two partitions inside the LVM2, I get the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Also, when I run fdisk, it shows the two partitions as not containing "a valid partition table"

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 160.0 GB, 16004188696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002d815

Device      Boot    Start       End     Blocks      Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *   63      305234      152586      83  Linux
/dev/sdd2       305235      4498199     2096482+    82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdd3       4498200     312576704   154039252+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylindars, total 41943040
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_usr2: 136.2 GB, 136197439488 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 16558 cylindars, total 266010624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-lv_usr2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Here are the contents of lvdisplay:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup00/lv_root
  VG Name                VolGroup00
  LV UUID                jOeBez-2QxJ-Rwth-ufsK-kohE-dHrW-XwDeEi
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                20.00 GiB
  Current LE             640
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VolGroup00/lv_usr2
  VG Name                VolGroup00
  LV UUID                YvbvFJ-yq2t-gSoV-6CqL-Imby-qx6E-uNu3Iz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                126.84 GiB
  Current LE             4059
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Do you guys have any advice? I am positive they are ext3 partitions..

Comment: What is the command you're using to try to mount the volumes?

Comment: Your mount command output shows you're trying to mount `/dev/loop0`, not one of your lvm volumes (`/dev/VolGroup00/lv_usr2` or `/dev/VolGroup00/lv_root`). 
Also lvm volumes don't contain partition tables, so that `fdisk` output is expected. Use `blkid` if you want to get a list of identifiable volumes.

Comment: @Patrick, strickly speaking, nothing's stopping you from putting MBR or GPT, BSD disklabel... partitions on a logical volume (and typically virtual machines that have their virtual disk on a LV on the host will have some of those), but the kernel does not expose those partitions automatically as block devices (nothing's stopping a user space program from creating more mapper devices for them though)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, that is correct. An LVM volume is a block device, just like a physical drive. Anything you put on one can go on the other. However, putting a partition table on a LVM volume is not a common practice, and I would go as far as to say that is almost never done. Also why I said "don't contain", and not "can't contain" :-)

Comment: @Patrick, I agree it's no help to the OP and it's nitpicking, but as I said, it's common to have VM disk images on LVs, so it's common to have partitions (all sorts of partitions even LVM themselves) on LVs.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with ext2/ext3 formatted logical volumes it's been my experience that you don't need to provide the filesystem type to mount.

Given your output from `lvdisplay` you should be mounting one of 2 logical volumes like this:

```
 $ mount /dev/VolGroup00/lv_root /mnt
 -or-
 $ mount /dev/VolGroup00/lv_usr2 /mnt
```

If something is wrong with either, you can use the command `lvscan` to make sure they're active.

#### Example

```
$ lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00' [228.53 GB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01' [1.94 GB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/kodak_vg/lvm0' [149.00 GB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/lvm-raid2/lvm0' [2.73 TB] inherit
```

If it isn't active you can set it with `vgchange`.

#### Example

```
$ vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "VolGroup00" now active
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "kodak_vg" now active
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "lvm-raid2" now active
```

Which will set them all back to active.